# RegEX: Replace Semicolon ";" in csv file between marks

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

I have CSV file like:

```
XXX;YYY;AAA;SSS;<p>lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum;<p>lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum;lorem ipsum</p>lorem ipsum</p>;QQQ;WWW
```

and I want to replace semicolon ';' with comma ',' but only between HTML p tags. I have notepad++ and I need correct RegEx expression.
I write something but notepad always delete all string.

Answer (score 1):

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `<p>[^;]+\K;(?=.*</p>)`
- **Replace With:** `,`
- Check **regular expression**
- Click Replace or Replace All
- due to the odd nature of the match, each replace replaces only one semicolon. You have to keep <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> pressed until there is no more semicolon left (just keep it pressed for a few seconds), the status bar in the find dialog tells you when it is done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex in notepad++ to search the semicolon and replace it:
**find what:** `<p>(.*?);(.*?)<p>`
**replace with:** `<p>\1,\2<p>`

[image]